# Python permutations of a huge matrix

Tags: python

I want to create permutations of a matrix, which has 10 rows with 70 items each.
Every item contains either `True` or `False`. I need to create permutations of this matrix.
The problem is that I would need to write 1400 `for` statements.
Is there a better way to do these permutations?

```
matrix = [[False for i in range(0, 70)] for i in range(0, 10)]
possible_items = [True, False]
```

Edit: Loop through all possible combinations of all `True` and `False` items in the matrix.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you mean by "permutations of a matrix"?

Comment: You propose to loop over 2^700 matrices. This is roughly 5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 matrices. This is not something you can achieve; find a different way to solve your underlying problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree 100% with the comment made by @user2357112, there must be an underlying issue with your solution that prompted you to pursue such a solution.

However, if for any reason you do want a solution to this you might consider using [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```
VALUES = (True, False)
rows = itertools.product(VALUES, repeat=70)
```

This will produce all rows of 70 items of `VALUES`, I do not suggest running it.

You can then easily extend this to be a solution to your problem, but I repeat, this is probably *not* a good way to do this.